# Azure DevOps npm build wrong folder

Tags: reactjs, npm, azure-devops

I am building build pipeline for react.js project.
The two first steps are

> npm install

and

> npm run build --prod

The first one is working. However the second one is not. I choose good working folder that contains package.json - `Web/{AppName}`
The same `Web/{AppName}` is used as directory to npm install command which works fine.

The error while running build command is:

```
4 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\agent\_workDC45Build\7\s\Web\package.json'
```

Why this step is looking for package.json in Web folder instead of Web/{AppName} which is just set in build configuration?

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: Can you share your pipeline?

Comment: Just editted see image

Comment: Try to add the beginning: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Web\SmartShopping

Comment: exactly the same error

Comment: If you click on the `...` in the right and explicit choose the folder is it success? and try use \ and noy `/` like I see in the photo.

Comment: Choosing from ... == string as on image. What do you mean use and noy?

Comment: I meant \  and not / but in think is not will change anything because if you choose from the ui you got `/`

Comment: not impossible that the npm-task has an issue here... can you use "Command line task" for "npm build" instead and check if that works ?

Comment: I created power Shell task instead which workd